# Getting it across

Tags: creative-writing, world-building

I'm having trouble wording something so people understand it.

I have a man across the street from someone holding up a wallet in the air up to another guy across the street. The guy across the street is pretending to grab it.

"Pretending to grab the wallet, Mike smiled and walked off."

Would this get the point across, or something like "Air-grabbing the wallet, Mike...

thanks

Comment: Hi. Questions asking **how to rephrase** are off-topic here. Please have a look at https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: ('catch the wallet' makes more sense than 'grab')